# Attributes of text above specific bar with ios-charts

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios-charts

How can I change attributes (e.g. font size, text color, etc...) of text above a specific bar in a BarChart?

[image: Bar chart example.]

In this example, I want *"-$5,000.00"* in red and to increase the font size of every text above bars.

Here's some code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var barChartView: BarChartView!


// init barChartView --------------------------------------
barChartView.descriptionText = ""

barChartView.legend.enabled = false

// grid lines
barChartView.xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
barChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
barChartView.leftAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
barChartView.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
barChartView.rightAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
barChartView.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false

// X-axis line
barChartView.xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = true
barChartView.xAxis.axisLineColor = axisGridsAndLabelsColor

// X-axis labels
barChartView.xAxis.labelTextColor = axisGridsAndLabelsColor
barChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .Bottom

// Y-axis labels
accountsBarChartView.leftAxis.labelTextColor = axisGridsAndLabelsColor
accountsBarChartView.rightAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
//---------------------------------------------------------


// bar chart's data
var dataPoints = [String]()
var values = [Double]()
var colors = [UIColor]()

// build bar chart's data...


// dataEntries and barChartDataSet
var dataEntries = [ChartDataEntry]()
for i in 0..<dataPoints.count
{
    let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i)
    dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
}

let barChartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: "")
barChartDataSet.colors = colors


// valueFormatter
let currencyNumberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
currencyNumberFormatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
currencyNumberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
currencyNumberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2

barChartDataSet.valueFormatter = currencyNumberFormatter


// barChartData
let barChartData = BarChartData(xVals: dataPoints, dataSet: barChartDataSet)
barChartView.data = barChartData
```

Comment: create outlets to the text labels and change their attributes? like textLabelXY.fontsize etc?

Comment: what have you tryed so far?

Comment: I don't think I can create outlets from labels inside a `BarChartView`.
I tried to find some property of `BarChartDataSet`, but the only one involving those labels I found was `valueFormatter`, which operates on `String`s (not on `NSAttributedString`).

Comment: well. i don't know the framework you're using. but what is it build in interface builder? or is it just set promatically?

Comment: how does the "-$5000" gets into the "label"?

Comment: I programmatically built a `BarChartDataSet` for the `BarChartView` from X and Y values. Using the `valueFormatter` property of `BarChartDataSet` I converted `Double` values into `String`s like *"-$5,000.00"*, but I couldn't control font size or text color.

Comment: okay. could you please post the code you're using to sent the string to the barchart

Comment: I edited the first post with sample code.

Comment: what options does f.e. `barChartView.xAxis.`offer? if you enter the "." at the end? are there any options to define the text color?

Comment: and you only want to edit the color for a "specific" bar?

Comment: i think a possibility should be within the framework. where the text label itself is specified. something like `if string == < 0 { font.color = UIColor.redcolor }` or something like this. but we need to find the class or method that defines the label...

Comment: @horothesun can you share how to access the label above bar charts in swift 2 ??
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41979926/how-to-achieve-trackball-and-access-label-above-bar-on-bar-charts-in-swift-3x

Comment: How did you add Bank #1 , Bank#2 and so on? Could you help me , please? [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46618636/how-to-add-string-labels-to-horizontal-bar-in-charts-framework/)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To set your own colors/font you can use properties `valueColors` and 'valueFont' of `BarChartDataSet` class

So it'll be something like this

```
...

var valueColors = [UIColor]()
// dataEntries and barChartDataSet
var dataEntries = [ChartDataEntry]()
for i in 0..<dataPoints.count
{
    let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i)
    dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    if values[i] < 0 {
        valueColors.append(UIColor.redColor())
    }
    else {
        valueColors.append(UIColor.greenColor())
    }
}

let barChartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: "")
barChartDataSet.colors = colors
barChartDataSet.valueColors = valueColors
barChartDataSet.valueFont = *font you want*
```

Comment: How can i Change the label above bar in swift2 ??
I have achieved this in swift 3
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41979926/how-to-achieve-trackball-on-charts-in-swift-3x

Comment: Is it also possible to change value font like attributedString?

Comment: To add an eample so that a newbie can try it easily; 
barChartDataSet.valueFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 8)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the text attributes of labels **below** bars you can use:

`barChartView.xAxis.labelFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 5)`

`barChartView.xAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor.red`