# How to add string labels( xAxis labels) to horizontal bar in Charts framework

Tags: ios, swift, charts

I am using [charts framework](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/) for drawing charts. I need to add some strings in left of every bars. In my code always there are two bars, one for **Income** and one for **Expense**. I want to show these string aside of every bar.

[image: Horizontal bar]

Below you can see my codes:

```
            let ys1 = [model.totalIncome, abs(model.totalExpense)]

            var yse1 = ys1.enumerated().map { x, y -> BarChartDataEntry in
            return BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(x), y: y)
            }

            let count = 2
            let data = BarChartData()
            let ds1 = BarChartDataSet(values: yse1, label: "")
            ds1.colors = [UIColor.red, UIColor.blue]

            // Number formatting of Values
            ds1.valueFormatter = YAxisValueFormatter()
            ds1.valueFont = UIFont(fontType: .H6)!
            ds1.valueTextColor = UIColor.dark_text

            // Data set
            data.addDataSet(ds1)
            horizontalBarChartView.data = data

            // General setting
            horizontalBarChartView.xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
            horizontalBarChartView.setScaleEnabled(false)

            // Grid
            horizontalBarChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
            horizontalBarChartView.leftAxis.gridLineDashLengths = [15.0, 15.0]
            horizontalBarChartView.leftAxis.gridColor = UIColor.palette_28
            horizontalBarChartView.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false


            // Disable number formatting of leftAxis and rightAxis
            horizontalBarChartView.leftAxis.enabled = false
            horizontalBarChartView.rightAxis.enabled = false

            horizontalBarChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = 
            IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: ["Income","Expense"])
            horizontalBarChartView.xAxis.granularityEnabled = true
            horizontalBarChartView.xAxis.granularity = 1


            // setViewPortOffsets
            let digitCount = Int(data.yMax).digitCount
            let leftOffcet: CGFloat = digitCount > 2 ? CGFloat((digitCount - 1) * 10) : 10.0
            horizontalBarChartView.setViewPortOffsets(left: leftOffcet, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 50)

            horizontalBarChartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0
```

And my view:

```
   lazy var horizontalBarChartView: HorizontalBarChartView = {
        let chartView = HorizontalBarChartView()
        chartView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        chartView.drawBordersEnabled = false
        chartView.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = false
        chartView.gridBackgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        chartView.legend.enabled = false
        chartView.chartDescription = nil
        chartView.highlighter = nil
        chartView.clipsToBounds = true
        chartView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return chartView
    }()
```

I guess below code should add these labels, however, it is not working

```
    horizontalBarChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: ["Income","Expense"])
    horizontalBarChartView.xAxis.granularityEnabled = true
    horizontalBarChartView.xAxis.granularity = 1
```

***Update***

See orange rectangle. I need these labels.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Charts framework is a great tool for drawing charts. You should study it perfectly. I used an old code in our project (copy/paste), so it caused some problems for drawing xAxis labels in my chart.

Just comment below line:

```
    horizontalBarChartView.xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 4):

I am using an extension for this

```
extension BarChartView {

    private class BarChartFormatter: NSObject, IAxisValueFormatter {

        var labels: [String] = []

        func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
            return labels[Int(value)]
        }

        init(labels: [String]) {
            super.init()
            self.labels = labels
        }
    }

    func setBarChartData(xValues: [String], yValues: [Double], label: String) {

        var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []

        for i in 0..<yValues.count {
            let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: yValues[i])
            dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
        }

        let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: label)
        let chartData = BarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)

        let chartFormatter = BarChartFormatter(labels: xValues)
        let xAxis = XAxis()
        xAxis.valueFormatter = chartFormatter
        self.xAxis.valueFormatter = xAxis.valueFormatter

        self.data = chartData
    }
}
```

you can use this in code like this

```
chartView.setBarChartData(xValues: xEntries, yValues: yEntries, label: "Income")
```

where,

```
//You need to add values dynamically
var yEntries: [Double] = [1000, 200, 500]
var xEntries: [String] = ["Income1", "Income2", "Income3"]
```

Hope this works.

Comment: how to center xValues related with bar, i'm try with `self.xAxis.centerAxisLabelsEnabled = true` but not works

Answer (score 0):

When you create your `BarChartDataSet` you can pass the label.

```
let data = BarChartData()
let ds1 = BarChartDataSet(values: yse1, label: "Income")
ds1.colors = [UIColor.red, UIColor.blue]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
 self.ChartObj.xAxis.valueFormatter = DefaultAxisValueFormatter(block: {(index, _) in
            print(index)
            return YourArray.object(at: Int(index)) as! String
        })
 self.ChartObj.xAxis.setLabelCount(YourArray.count, force: true)
```

Try this code